# Configuring salt stack on virtualbox manually

Tags: linux, saltstack

First time using salt stack.

I configured salt stack on three virtual box machines. All three machines are set up as bridged networks. Centos7(Master), Centos7(minion), Ubuntu(minion). On the master, I installed the update using:

`sudo rpm --import https://repo.saltproject.io/salt/py3/redhat/7/x86_64/SALT-PROJECT-GPG-PUBKEY-2023.pub curl -fsSL https://repo.saltproject.io/salt/py3/redhat/7/x86_64/latest.repo | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/salt.repo`

I created a config file in the master.d directory called master.conf and set the interface value to the static private Ipv4 address for the master machine. Then I installed salt-master on the machine, started, and enabled the service.

On the minions, I configured a static IP, downloaded salt-minion, and started and enabled the service.

Since I wasn't using DNS, I mapped all of the IP addresses in the /etc/hosts file for each machine.

When I went on the master machine to check for pending keys none of the minions appeared.

I ran the debugger on the master and received the error "Unable to bind socket #.#.#.#:4505, error: [Errno 98] Address already in use; Is there another salt-master running?" (replaced actual my ip with "#")

I then killed all of the processes containing "salt-master", and restarted the service but nothing worked.

Then I allowed the firewall for the master, and restarted the service but no pending keys appeared.

Is there something I am missing in this setup?

How would you recreate this from scratch?

Comment: https://docs.saltproject.io/salt/install-guide/en/latest/